# Laravel Nova installation - There are no commands defined in the "nova" namespace

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-nova, laravel-artisan

I'm trying to [install Laravel Nova according to the docs](https://nova.laravel.com/docs/2.0/installation.html#installing-nova) in a Laravel 5.8 project. As directed, I added this to my `composer.json` file:

```
"repositories": [
    {
        "type": "composer",
        "url": "https://nova.laravel.com"
    }
],
```

and in the `require` section:

```
"laravel/nova": "~2.0",
```

Then I ran `composer update` (and provided my id and password), and it installed the nova packages successfully, and I can see them listed in my `composer.lock` file.

The next step is meant to be `php artisan nova:install`, however, that gives me:

> There are no commands defined in the "nova" namespace.

This kind of thing is often fixed by `composer dumpautoload` or `php artisan config:clear`, however, neither helped. I tried it using a zip download and a `path`-type repo config, which did the same. I also tried the more violent `php artisan config:cache`, but that didn't help either.

What have I missed?

Comment: Have you tried `php artisan clear-compiled` [source](https://github.com/laravel/nova-issues/issues/841#issuecomment-455557062)

Comment: That did it! It's very annoying that these things happen so often...

Comment: @Remul it will be good, if you can post it as solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try running `php artisan clear-compiled`

> The `clear-compiled` command is used to clear the compiled classes and
>   services application cache. These two files are located in the
>   `bootstrap/cache/` directory. The compiled classes cache is stored in a
>   file named `compiled.php` and the services cache is stored in a file
>   named `services.php`. This command will remove both of these files if
>   they exist.

[Source](https://github.com/laravel/nova-issues/issues/841#issuecomment-455557062)

Answer (score 1):

Use composer dump-autoload before proceeding to Laravel Nova installation.
It'll work fine then.

Comment: Glad to hear that sir.
Happy Coding.:)